# Use Google Engine URL to fetch google doc got java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: google-app-engine

Within google engine, I can fetch other URLs on the web, but I cannot fetch a google doc (I tried the normal java url connection and it has no problem to fetch the google doc).

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching: https://docs.google.com/uc....

```
      OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
        URL url = new URL("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-UWER27gDKlUjRkT2czVXpzNDg");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        // URL url = new URL("http://www.gradsch.ohio-state.edu/Depo/ETD_Tutorial/lesson2.pdf");
        System.out.println(url);
         byte b[] = new byte[2048];
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        int len;
        while ((len=is.read(b))!=-1)
        {
            os.write(b, 0, len);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a deadline for a request, the most amount of time the service will wait for a response. By default, the deadline for a fetch is 5 seconds

```
conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);  //60 Seconds
conn.setReadTimeout(60000);  //60 Seconds
```

Please take a look at the document here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview#Fetching_URLs_with_java_net